# PHP unknown column number

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have a small issue I ran into and would like to figure out the logic behind it. On my website, I have a form where admin will submit various info regarding a user, including some links. Now, I have no idea how many links there will be, maybe 5, maybe 35. Point is I don't know the upper limit, so how would I go about making that form? Here's an idea that might work:

Once add customer form is open, I'll have the admin type in the number of links for submission;
Based on that number, input fields would be created;
PHP will then check if columns already exist, if not, it will create & submit them;
Display page for customer will then select * from data and display it accordingly;

Here's what I don't know how to pull off here:
How do I create X input fields based on number X?
How do I make php add columns like this: Link1, Link1status (predefined), Link2, Link2status (predefined). etc?
How do I make the display page for customer echo only the number of links present in a similar fashion: Link1: $Link1 Link1status: $Link1status etc.

I'm not looking for you to write the code for me, I'm just having issues with logic where I need to create html based on some number.

Thank you for your help!
Best
Fisher

Comment: Use javascript instead of PHP, possibly? Think of a loop where the name of the field is `link + i`, where `i` is the counter in your javascript loop. You can even create a "add another field" button that will add a field with the incremented `link + i`, if you kept track of the value of `i`.

Comment: you can dynamically add the rows to this table using strategies like `.append()`, keep the field name with a `[]` i.e. `name="row[]"` so that php will translate it to an array at form submit and you will get the `count($_POST['row'])` to tell you how many there is.

Comment: Thank you I'm reading documentation regarding .append() at the moment, once I have the code complete I will submit it here as a reply =)

Thanks zdhickman, I think DevZer0's method will allow me to use most of the code I already have tho I will look into your method if I can't make this work. 

Many thanks for swift replies!

Answer (score 1):

You can make two separate tables, one with the users, one with all links.

```
Table users with columns (ID, name (for example), ...)
Table links with columns (ID, user_id, link, link_status (for example), ...)
```

Example: you have the user 'John Doe' with three properties, let's say hair color (brown), length (180 cm) and weight (80 kg), you get this:

```
Table users with 1 row > (1, John Doe) //(ID, color)
Table links with 3 rows > (1, 1, hair color, brown), (2, 1, length, 180 cm), (3, 1, weight, 80 kg) //(ID, user_id, property, value)
```

You can apply this on your system. If you want to get all links of an user, just search in the 'links' table with the 'user_id'.

To make a form for the insertion of this records, use a table with one starting row and a hidden row with empty inputs. A user can add more rows with inputs to add links (you can use jQuery's `clone()` function to copy the hidden row with empty inputs). You can use `name=array[]` (with the inputs) to get an array result after POST.

Comment: Yes, that's right. If you ever design a database and find that you need multiple columns which are basically in the form option1, option2, option3, ... , optionX you have a bad design that has to be normalized following this answer instruvtion

Comment: How would I keep the links there? In the same column? For some reason, I thought it would be easier if each link had it's own column and status column for easier manipulation & updating

Comment: You can store all links in seperated rows with a link to the user_id. That's the best way if you don't know how many links per user are inserted.

Answer (score 1):

As in the comments, you should probably use a javascript based solution:

Just have a button to "add another link":

```
<div class="links-wrap">
    <input type="text">
</div>
<a class="new-link">Add another link</a>
```

Then:

```
$('.new-link').click(function() {
    $('.links-wrap').append('<input type="text">');
});
```

Then you can pull the data from all link fields.

Comment: +1 for the good explanation, you should probably emphasize on the `name` attribute also

Comment: Okay so I do this and I store it as suggested above with USER ID and LINK columns. Then when I wanna display this I count how many links are there and generate HTML based on that number. The only thing is: how would I do this? Html needs to show Link: Linkname Linkstatus : status.

Also, when I update the status, do I look for the link name in the column links and for that link name update the status of it? Thanks a lot!

Comment: @DevZer0 would that simply be `<input type="text" name="row[]">`or does the row[] need some sort of incremented counter? My knowledge of PHP is pretty basic, but would be good to include it in the answer.

Comment: @SamFisher That was a bit of a convoluted question :P I imagine you are building an array with this data, correct? [Take a look at this](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=31840&seqNum=3) for help on pulling stuff out of arrays. Apologies if that is way off what you meant.

Comment: i will add to your answer later i am going out now

Answer (score 0):

You can use javascript to add links as you complete the form (like an "add new field button"), which will allow you to create as many inputs as you want. But if you want to keep it simple, just replace all the fields for the links with an textarea, and have the admin to add the links separated by colon or semicolon. All you have to do is to use the `explode` function to get the links before add them to the database or whatever you want to do with them.